# Maven build fails upon compiling widgetset

Tags: maven, build, vaadin, gwt-maven-plugin

I am having trouble compiling my widgetset using maven and vaadin. when i run this command:

```
mvn vaadin:update-widgetset install
```

Stack trace

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.197s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jan 14 11:30:02 CST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:1.0.1:update-widgetset (default-cli) @ Dugsi_Manager ---
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt-maven-plugin/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt-maven-plugin/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt-maven-plugin/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt-maven-plugin/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to codehaus-snapshots ([http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots): No connector available to access repository codehaus-snapshots ([http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[INFO] establishing classpath list (scope = compile)
[ERROR] Jan 14, 2012 11:30:40 AM com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.ClassPathExplorer getAvailableWidgetSets
[ERROR] INFO: Widgetsets found from classpath:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Jan 14, 2012 11:30:40 AM com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.ClassPathExplorer getAvailableWidgetSets
[ERROR] INFO: Search took 6ms
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile (default) @ Dugsi_Manager ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ Dugsi_Manager ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.1.0-1:resources (default) @ Dugsi_Manager ---
[INFO] auto discovered modules [org.bixin.dugsi.web.DugsiManagerWidgetset]
[INFO] 1 source files from GWT module org.bixin.dugsi.web.DugsiManagerWidgetset
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ Dugsi_Manager ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:1.0.1:update-widgetset (default) @ Dugsi_Manager ---
[INFO] auto discovered modules [org.bixin.dugsi.web.DugsiManagerWidgetset]
[INFO] Updating widgetset org.bixin.dugsi.web.DugsiManagerWidgetset
[INFO] establishing classpath list (scope = compile)
[ERROR] Jan 14, 2012 11:30:43 AM com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.ClassPathExplorer getAvailableWidgetSets
[ERROR] INFO: Widgetsets found from classpath:
[ERROR]     org.vaadin.jouni.animator.AnimatorWidgetset in jar:file:/Users/warz07/.m2/repository/org/vaadin/addons/animator/1.6.3/animator-1.6.3.jar!/
[ERROR]     com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet in jar:file:/Users/warz07/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.7.1/vaadin-6.7.1.jar!/
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Jan 14, 2012 11:30:43 AM com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.ClassPathExplorer getAvailableWidgetSets
[ERROR] INFO: Search took 5ms
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:test-compile (default) @ Dugsi_Manager ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ Dugsi_Manager ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Dugsi_Manager ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.8:test (default-test) @ Dugsi_Manager ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/warz07/Documents/workspace-sts-2.8.0.RELEASE/trunk1/target/surefire-reports
[INFO] 
[INFO]    Validating newly compiled units
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/warz07/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.7.1/vaadin-6.7.1.jar!/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/Util.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 35: The import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Touch cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 1163: The method getChangedTouches() is undefined for the type Event
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 1179: The method getChangedTouches() is undefined for the type Event
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 1215: Touch cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 1215: The method getChangedTouches() is undefined for the type Event
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/warz07/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.7.1/vaadin-6.7.1.jar!/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/ui/TouchScrollDelegate.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 26: The import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Touch cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 27: The import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.TouchStartEvent cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 129: TouchStartEvent cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 132: Touch cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 234: Touch cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 309: Touch cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 309: The method getChangedTouches() is undefined for the type NativeEvent
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 465: Event.ONTOUCHMOVE cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 473: Event.ONTOUCHEND cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 474: Event.ONTOUCHCANCEL cannot be resolved
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/warz07/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.7.1/vaadin-6.7.1.jar!/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/ui/VAudio.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 19: The import com.google.gwt.dom.client.AudioElement cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 30: AudioElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 33: AudioElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 33: The method createAudioElement() is undefined for the type Document
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 34: AudioElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 44: AudioElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/warz07/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.7.1/vaadin-6.7.1.jar!/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/ui/VDragAndDropWrapper.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 30: The import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.TouchStartEvent cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 31: The import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.TouchStartHandler cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 87: TouchStartHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 96: TouchStartEvent cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 97: Event.TOUCHEVENTS cannot be resolved
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/warz07/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.7.1/vaadin-6.7.1.jar!/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/ui/VMediaBase.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 20: The import com.google.gwt.dom.client.MediaElement cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 40: MediaElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 48: MediaElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 50: MediaElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 60: MediaElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 61: MediaElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 62: MediaElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 71: MediaElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 121: MediaElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 130: MediaElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 136: MediaElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/warz07/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.7.1/vaadin-6.7.1.jar!/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/ui/VMenuBar.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 793: The method setOverflowY(Style.Overflow) is undefined for the type Style
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/warz07/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.7.1/vaadin-6.7.1.jar!/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/ui/VPanel.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 24: The import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.TouchStartEvent cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 25: The import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.TouchStartHandler cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 132: Event.TOUCHEVENTS cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 135: TouchStartHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 139: TouchStartEvent cannot be resolved
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/warz07/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.7.1/vaadin-6.7.1.jar!/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/ui/VScrollTable.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 42: The import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Touch cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 58: The import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.TouchStartEvent cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 59: The import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.TouchStartHandler cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 460: Event.TOUCHEVENTS cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 461: TouchStartHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 465: TouchStartEvent cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 2285: Event.TOUCHEVENTS cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 2384: Event.ONTOUCHEND cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 2398: Event.ONTOUCHSTART cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 2458: Event.ONTOUCHSTART cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 2461: Event.ONTOUCHSTART cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 2477: Event.ONTOUCHEND cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 2478: Event.ONTOUCHCANCEL cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 2539: Event.ONTOUCHMOVE cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 2542: Event.ONTOUCHMOVE cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 4466: Event.TOUCHEVENTS cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 4999: Event.ONTOUCHEND cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 5000: Event.ONTOUCHCANCEL cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 5013: Event.ONTOUCHMOVE cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 5037: Event.ONTOUCHSTART cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 5039: Touch cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 5039: The method getChangedTouches() is undefined for the type Event
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 5139: Touch cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 5139: The method getChangedTouches() is undefined for the type Event
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/warz07/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.7.1/vaadin-6.7.1.jar!/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/ui/VSlider.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 124: Event.TOUCHEVENTS cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 395: Event.ONTOUCHSTART cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 410: Event.ONTOUCHMOVE cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 418: Event.ONTOUCHEND cannot be resolved
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/warz07/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.7.1/vaadin-6.7.1.jar!/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/ui/VSplitPanel.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 25: The import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.TouchCancelEvent cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 26: The import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.TouchCancelHandler cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 27: The import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.TouchEndEvent cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 28: The import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.TouchEndHandler cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 29: The import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.TouchMoveEvent cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 30: The import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.TouchMoveHandler cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 31: The import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.TouchStartEvent cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 32: The import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.TouchStartHandler cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 190: TouchCancelHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 195: TouchCancelEvent cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 196: TouchStartHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 206: TouchStartEvent cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 207: TouchMoveHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 213: TouchMoveEvent cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 214: TouchEndHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 220: TouchEndEvent cannot be resolved
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/warz07/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.7.1/vaadin-6.7.1.jar!/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/ui/VTabsheetPanel.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 21: The import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.TouchStartEvent cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 22: The import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.TouchStartHandler cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 49: Event.TOUCHEVENTS cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 50: TouchStartHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 65: TouchStartEvent cannot be resolved
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/warz07/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.7.1/vaadin-6.7.1.jar!/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/ui/VTree.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 613: Event.TOUCHEVENTS cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 830: Event.ONTOUCHSTART cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 834: Event.ONTOUCHSTART cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 857: Event.ONTOUCHMOVE cannot be resolved
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/warz07/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.7.1/vaadin-6.7.1.jar!/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/ui/VVideo.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 21: The import com.google.gwt.dom.client.VideoElement cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 32: VideoElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 35: VideoElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 35: The method createVideoElement() is undefined for the type Document
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 36: VideoElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 53: VideoElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 80: VideoElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 81: VideoElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/warz07/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.7.1/vaadin-6.7.1.jar!/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/ui/VWindow.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 292: Event.TOUCHEVENTS cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 927: Event.ONTOUCHSTART cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 944: Event.ONTOUCHEND cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 946: Event.ONTOUCHCANCEL cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 956: Event.ONTOUCHMOVE cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 1141: Event.ONTOUCHSTART cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 1142: The method getTouches() is undefined for the type Event
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 1152: Event.ONTOUCHEND cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 1153: Event.ONTOUCHCANCEL cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 1158: Event.ONTOUCHMOVE cannot be resolved
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/warz07/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin/6.7.1/vaadin-6.7.1.jar!/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/ui/dd/VDragAndDropManager.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 116: Event.ONTOUCHMOVE cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 210: Event.ONTOUCHMOVE cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 218: Event.ONTOUCHEND cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 357: Event.ONTOUCHSTART cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 401: Event.ONTOUCHMOVE cannot be resolved
[INFO]    Finding entry point classes
[INFO]       [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.ApplicationConfiguration'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
[INFO]          [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 48.076s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jan 14 11:31:20 CST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.1.0-1:compile (default) on project Dugsi_Manager: Command [[
```

I am running vaadin 6.7 and my gwt-maven plugin is 2.1.0-1, i also have the eclipse-plugin installed which recognizes any new addons and automatic tries to compile.

Which gwt-maven plugin version is suppposed to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try gwt-maven-plugin version to 2.3.0-1 and vaadin-maven-plugin 1.0.2. These work for me in Vaadin 6.6.8 and they should work in 6.7.x as well as pointed out in [here](http://vaadin.com/download/release/6.7/6.7.4/release-notes.html#dependencies)

Comment: This led to changing and updating several other things and eventually being able to compile my widget set. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Working with this settings every day

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    ....

<groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    ....
```